# When i run this code it gives me a "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" error

Tags: java, jfxtras

```
    package teste1;  
    import javafx.application.Application;  
    import javafx.scene.Scene;  
    import javafx.stage.Stage;  
    import java.time.LocalDate;  
    import jfxtras.scene.control.agenda.Agenda;  
    public class Teste1 extends Application  
    {  
        @Override  
        public void start(Stage primaryStage)  
        {  
            // Creates an Agenda.  
            Agenda agenda = new Agenda();  
            // Adds an Appointment to it.  
            agenda.appointments().addAll  
            (  
                new Agenda.AppointmentImplLocal()  
                .withStartLocalDateTime(LocalDate.now().atTime(4, 00))  
                .withEndLocalDateTime(LocalDate.now().atTime(15, 30))  
                .withDescription("It's Time!")  
                .withAppointmentGroup(new Agenda.AppointmentGroupImpl().withStyleClass("Group1")));  
                // Shows the Agenda.  
                primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(agenda, 800, 600));  
                primaryStage.show();  
        }  
        public static void main(String[] args)  
        {  
            launch(args);  
        }  
    }
```

I imported the jfxtras-agenda-8.0-r5.jar and the jfxtras-controls-8.0-r5.jar to the Project.

When i run this code it gives me a "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException". Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Please format this illegible mess, including removing all the redundant blank lines, and provide he complete stack trace in your question. The answer lies in it.

Comment: And you're supposed to post some text explaining your code and your problem -- you do neither, but rather only a very brief explanation in the title. Please up the quality of this question.

Comment: Your code from here: http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-agenda/jfxtras/scene/control/agenda/Agenda.html and there is an explanation for that

Comment: Without the full stacktrace of the exception, it is impossible to answer this question. But do use the 8.0-r6-SNAPSHOT, it has many bugfixes and is up for a new release.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your example and there are no errors.  Agenda opened up properly and the appointment appeared correct.  One difference is that I used the latest JFXtras 8.0-r6-SNAPSHOT.  Please try the new snapshot.  I suggest you add the dependency to a Maven or Gradle build file.

If you still have a problem please provide the entire stacktrace so I can better help you.

Comment: I just found out what was the error: the library jfxtras-common-8.0-r5.jar was missing from the Project. Now it works fine. Sorry about the code, i still didn't figured out very well how to format the java code :(